# How can I get and show meta informations (stations name, current song, bitrate, etc) when playing a radio stream with HTML5 audio?

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

How could I retrieve the current song title, radio stations name and other meta info from a radio stream played with Html5?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

AudCurs=new Audio();


$('#play').click(function(){
AudCurs.setAttribute('src','http://62.27.26.45:8000/klassikradio128/livestream.mp3');

AudCurs.play();

});
});


</script>

<button id='play' >Play</button>
```

thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML5 standard and Mozilla, there are not many details which you can fetch [[1](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#audio), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAudioElement), [3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement)].

You can get the sample rate:

```
var rate = AudCurs.playbackRate;
```

Probably your stream supports ID3 tags. If that's the case, you can fetch some additional infos: http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript

To fetch more details, I would recommend you to implement this on the server side and then fetch the results using AJAX and JQuery.

Comment: thx. i'm relatively new to this stuff. i got the playbackRate, but for the rest....does anyone has an working example?